# Using PlaceFilter with PlaceDetectionApi

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

I have tried following code.

```
    ArrayList<String> filters = new ArrayList<>();
    filters.add(Place.TYPE_ATM + "");
    filters.add(Place.TYPE_BANK + "");
    filters.add(Place.TYPE_BAR + "");
    filters.add(Place.TYPE_BUS_STATION + "");
    filters.add(Place.TYPE_DOCTOR + "");
    filters.add(Place.TYPE_FOOD + "");
    filters.add(Place.TYPE_ACCOUNTING + "");
    filters.add(Place.TYPE_AIRPORT + "");
    filters.add(Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT + "");
    filters.add("restaurant");
    filters.add("establishment");
    filters.add(Place.TYPE_STORE + "");
    PlaceFilter placeFilter = new PlaceFilter(false, filters);
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, placeFilter);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            Log.v("App", "1. likelyPlaces.getCount() : " + likelyPlaces.getCount());
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                for(int i : placeLikelihood.getPlace().getPlaceTypes()){
                    Log.i("App", String.format("Place '%s' with " +
                                    "likelihood: %g "+"type : %d",
                            placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                            placeLikelihood.getLikelihood(), i));
                }
            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
```

Which returns `likelyPlaces.getCount()` as 0.

But If I change `PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, placeFilter);` to `PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);` I can get the 20 places with placetypes `34, 1013, 38, 79, 88, 7`.

> So my question is Am I initiating `PlaceFilter` in wrong way?, if yes
>   how should I use `PlaceFilter` with `PlaceDetectionApi`?
>
> Also how can I get the place photo for all places?

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Integer values instead. Have a look at below link

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place

Comment: `Place.TYPE_ATM` this is integer value only, value for this is `6`. Look at same link for more details please.

Comment: Try filters.add(String.valueOf(Place.TYPE_ATM)). PlaceFilters use Parcelable and this might be misinterpreted. Not telling that it will work but is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

PlaceFilter constructor accepts place ids not place types.

PlaceFilter (boolean requireOpenNow, Collection restrictToPlaceIds)

That means you can't filter places by place types with PlaceDetectionApi. You can only restrict the results to given place ids in PlaceFilter passed to the api call.